# How to add one more column in same table while keeping the group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

List of columns in Table1:
Plan_ID, Claim_id, Patient_id, B_OR_G

List of columns in Table2:
ORGID, SHAPLANID

```
select distinct a.Plan_ID
       , a.Total_Claims
       , Total_Patients
       ,  b.PERIOD
       , b.ORGID,a.B_OR_G
FROM (Select distinct Plan_ID
             , count(distinct Claim_id) as Total_Claims
             , count(distinct Patient_id)  as Total_Patients 
      from table1 group by 1) a
JOIN (select *
             , row_number() over (partition by ORGID,SHAPLANID order by PROCESSINGDATE desc) as rank
      from table2 qualify rank = 1) b
ON LTRIM(a.PLAN_ID, '0') = b.SHAPLANID
```

In the above query I want to pull one more column named 'B_or_G' from table1 (i.e., a) but without disturbing the group by clause as it is necessary as per our requirement.

Is there any better way to do this?
Thanks!!

Comment: if it is grouped by 1 you can select max or min of that column ?

Comment: Your LTRIM function is not used correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use ANY_VALUE(B_or_G)

For your excample:

```html
select distinct a.Plan_ID
       , a.Total_Claims
       , Total_Patients
       ,  b.PERIOD
       , b.ORGID,a.B_OR_G
FROM (Select distinct Plan_ID
             , count(distinct Claim_id) as Total_Claims
             , count(distinct Patient_id)  as Total_Patients 
             , ANY_VALUE(B_OR_G)
      from table1 group by 1) a
JOIN (select *
             , row_number() over (partition by ORGID,SHAPLANID order by PROCESSINGDATE desc) as rank
      from table2 qualify rank = 1) b
ON LTRIM(a.PLAN_ID, '0') = b.SHAPLANID
```

,hope it help.

Comment: This definitely helped, Thanks Much!!
Please confirm, Using ANY_VALUE( ) will give exact mapped results to the other columns right? @bubbak